# .htaccess query rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache

I am trying to make it for when a client loads the website:

```
http://www.example.com/docs/example
```

To actually load the address:

```
http://www.example.com/docs.php?doc=example
```

But not have it redirect. I have had mixed success with this, but it seems that there is not clear documentation on how this specific rewrite rule is made. If I actually knew regular expressions, then it would make this a lot easier i understand, but I am seeking some help on how to perform this.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Previously I had attempted code similar to what @JonLin had posted, but had a little bit different code in terms of the regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?docs/(.*)$ /docs.php?doc=$1 [L]
```

Don't use the `http://hostname/` or the `R` flag and it shouldn't redirect.